# Use one router for internet and another for phone line

Tags: router, internet, dsl, phone, splitter

I got a new router much faster than my current one.
The problem with this router is that it doesn't support phone line.

I tried to connect both routers, the current one for the phone line, and the new one for internet, but for that I need DSL splitter which I don't have.

Is there a solution how the old's router phone line can work and the new router's internet? (without a DSL splitter)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You can't do that because you can only have one DSL device on a phone line, unless you coordinate that with your ISP,. The standard DSL 'modem' configuration scoops up all the frequencies above normal human voice information content (3,400Hz) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line . Please get the make and model number for each router device, then come back here, click [edit], and add that very useful information to your question, so all needed information is in the question (your channel to us). Please do not use Add Comment; that's our channel to you.